# PyTorch can't use a float type but only long

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to run this very basic neural network:

```
import os; os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"] = "TRUE"
import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#####################################################
#             Create the neural network             #
#####################################################

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


net = Net()

#####################################################
#                   Create the datasets             #
#####################################################


trainset = [torch.tensor([1., 1.**2]), torch.tensor([2., 2.**2]), torch.tensor([3., 3.**2]), torch.tensor([4., 4.**2]), torch.tensor([5., 5.**2]), torch.tensor([6., 6.**2]), torch.tensor([7., 7.**2]), torch.tensor([8., 8.**2])]

testset = [torch.tensor([1.1, 1.1**2]), torch.tensor([2.3, 2.3**2]), torch.tensor([3.1, 3.1**2]), torch.tensor([4.5, 4.5**2]), torch.tensor([5.9, 5.9**2]), torch.tensor([6.1, 6.1**2]), torch.tensor([7.3, 7.3**2]), torch.tensor([8.01, 8.01**2])]

#####################################################
#               Optimize the parameters             #
#####################################################

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)


EPOCHS = 3

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for data in trainset:
        x, y = data
        net.zero_grad()
        output = net(x.view(-1,1))
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, y.view(-1,1)[0])
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    print(loss)

#####################################################
#           Calculate the accuracy rate             #
#####################################################

correct = 0
total = 0

with torch.no_grad():
    for data in trainset:
        x, y = data
        output = net(x)
        if y - 0.01 < output < y + 0.01:
            correct += 1
        total += 1

print("Accuracy: %.2f" % (correct / total))
```

but I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\pythonProject\main.py", line 52, in 
> loss = F.nll_loss(output, y.view(-1,1)[0])   File "C:\WinPython\python-3.9.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py",
> line 2235, in nll_loss
> ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index) RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float

Why can't I use a float type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440292/runtimeerror-expected-scalar-type-long-but-found-float)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is our label should be integer scalar in `F.nll_loss` method read [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.functional.nll_loss.html).
Let me give one example, let say you want to do image classification , you cannot give your labels as `0.1 ,0.2 etc`, rather it should be `0,1,2 ..`

And I also see that , your labels are more that your model's output

working code should be something like this :

```
import os; os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"] = "TRUE"
import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#####################################################
#             Create the neural network             #
#####################################################

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 2) #  CHANGED TO 2 CLASS

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


net = Net()

#####################################################
#                   Create the datasets             #
#####################################################


trainset = [torch.tensor([1., 0.]), torch.tensor([2., 0.]), torch.tensor([3., 0.]), torch.tensor([4., 0.]), torch.tensor([5., 1.]), torch.tensor([6., 1.]), torch.tensor([7., 1.]), torch.tensor([8., 1.])]

testset = [torch.tensor([1.1, 0.]), torch.tensor([2.3, 0.]), torch.tensor([3.1, 0.]), torch.tensor([4.5, 0.]), torch.tensor([5.9, 1.]), torch.tensor([6.1, 1.]), torch.tensor([7.3,1.]), torch.tensor([8.01, 1.])]

#####################################################
#               Optimize the parameters             #
#####################################################

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)


EPOCHS = 3

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for data in trainset:
        x, y = data
        net.zero_grad()
        #print(x.view(-1,1).shape)
        y = torch.tensor([y.type(torch.LongTensor)])
        #print(y.shape)
        #print(y)
        output = net(x.view(-1,1))
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    print(loss)
```

Comment: Why can't I create a nn that return just one value? I want to create a network that simulates a quadratic function with x as input and sth similar to x**2 as output.

Comment: use MSE as your loss function@Andrea

Answer (score 1):

The negative log likelihood loss (NLLLoss) is suitable for classification problems, where the output is one out of C classes. Since the classes are discrete, your labels need to be of the long type.

In your case, in a comment, you say:

> I want to create a network that simulates a quadratic function with x as input and sth similar to x**2 as output.

This is a regression problem, where the output can have a real, continuous value. For this, you should use a suitable loss function such as the mean squared error loss ([MSELoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#mse-loss)). So, one way to fix would be changing `F.nll_loss` in your code to `F.mse_loss`.